# Message [JA002: SIMPLE authentication is not enabled. Available:[TOKEN]]

Tags: hadoop, oozie, sqoop

I get following error, while running a Oozie job.

Command:

```
oozie job -oozie http://10.xxx.xx.xx:11000/oozie/ -log 0000017-151029172404066-oozie-oozi-W
```

Logs:

```
2015-11-24 11:50:23,469  INFO ActionStartXCommand:543 - SERVER[hostname.abc.com] USER[oozie] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[sqoop-wf] JOB[0000017-151029172404066-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000017-151029172404066-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] Start action [0000017-151029172404066-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2015-11-24 11:50:23,470  INFO ActionStartXCommand:543 - SERVER[hostname.abc.com] USER[oozie] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[sqoop-wf] JOB[0000017-151029172404066-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000017-151029172404066-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000017-151029172404066-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action status=DONE
2015-11-24 11:50:23,470  INFO ActionStartXCommand:543 - SERVER[hostname.abc.com] USER[oozie] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[sqoop-wf] JOB[0000017-151029172404066-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000017-151029172404066-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000017-151029172404066-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action updated in DB!
2015-11-24 11:50:23,567  INFO ActionStartXCommand:543 - SERVER[hostname.abc.com] USER[oozie] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[sqoop-wf] JOB[0000017-151029172404066-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000017-151029172404066-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-node] Start action [0000017-151029172404066-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-node] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2015-11-24 11:50:24,323  WARN ActionStartXCommand:546 - SERVER[hostname.abc.com] USER[oozie] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[sqoop-wf] JOB[0000017-151029172404066-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000017-151029172404066-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-node] Error starting action [sqoop-node]. ErrorType [NON_TRANSIENT], ErrorCode [JA002], Message [JA002: SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN]]
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: JA002: SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN]
        at org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutor.convertExceptionHelper(ActionExecutor.java:418)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutor.convertException(ActionExecutor.java:392)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.submitLauncher(JavaActionExecutor.java:980)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.start(JavaActionExecutor.java:1135)
        at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:228)
        at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:63)
        at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:281)
        at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:323)
        at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:252)
        at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:174)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.instantiateException(RPCUtil.java:53)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.unwrapAndThrowException(RPCUtil.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.getDelegationToken(ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:309)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor46.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.getDelegationToken(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.getRMDelegationToken(YarnClientImpl.java:486)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ResourceMgrDelegate.getDelegationToken(ResourceMgrDelegate.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.getDelegationToken(YARNRunner.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.getDelegationToken(Cluster.java:400)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$16.run(JobClient.java:1240)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$16.run(JobClient.java:1237)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.getDelegationToken(JobClient.java:1236)
        at org.apache.oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.createJobClient(HadoopAccessorService.java:439)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.createJobClient(JavaActionExecutor.java:1178)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.submitLauncher(JavaActionExecutor.java:927)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN]
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1469)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1400)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.getDelegationToken(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.getDelegationToken(ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:306)
        ... 29 more
2015-11-24 11:50:24,324  WARN ActionStartXCommand:546 - SERVER[hostname.abc.com] USER[oozie] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[sqoop-wf] JOB[0000017-151029172404066-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000017-151029172404066-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-node] Suspending Workflow Job id=0000017-151029172404066-oozie-oozi-W
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, I was connecting to yarn scheduler instead of yarn resource manager.

In your oozie job.properties, make sure jobTracker url is pointing to yarn resource manager. Look for "yarn.resourcemanager.address" in your  yarn-site.xml